# absolute position rotated element to right corner

Tags: css, css-transitions

Im trying to figure out how to make shopping cart tab that would be positioned on the right corner and also rotated 90 degrees. The rotation naturally mixes the position but maybe there's a workaround of wrapping to different wrappers etc....

Extra points if there wouldn't need to define width. I don't care about older browsers

Answer (score 40):

How about using [**`transform-origin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin)? See [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3361555).

Relevant CSS:

```
#box {
    position: relative;
}
.bg {
    right: 40px; /* same as height */
    height: 40px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 40px; /* same as height, for vertical centering */
}
```

Comment: Brilliant wow I never would have realized that. I'll give it a go. THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks for this great suggestion! Is there an authoritative description of the support in different browsers for `tranform-origin`? The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#Browser_compatibility) is pretty incomplete at the moment.

Comment: As far as I know, it's supported in every browser that supports transforms. http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: This is transformed -90deg, it doesn't work so well for 90deg.

Answer (score 18):

[Ana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973680/988246) is excellent and pointed me in the right direction, but I realised you could achieve the same effect without having to explicitly set the height, line-height and position for the element you want to move - instead, just set `translate(0, -100%)`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
 right: 0;
 padding: 1em;
 transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(0, -100%);
 transform-origin: 100% 0;
 position: absolute;
 background: #FF1493;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
 <div class="bg">        
  <div class="txt">He's not the Messiah. He's a very naughty boy.</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

...and a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvvvv15w/52/) for good measure.

Comment: if you want to read the text the other way round, just add .txt { transform: rotate(180deg); }

Comment: there is a typo in your snippet and fiddle, btw - it should be class, not clss

Comment: I used this to turn it around:
transform: rotate(90deg) translate(100%,0); transform-origin: 100% 0;

Answer (score 7):

To rotate text at 90° using CSS, consider using [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode).

Set `position: relative;` on the parent div, then use something like this on the rotated element:

```
#rot {
    position: absolute; /* only handy here because its parent is set to `position: relative;` */
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    /* writing-mode: sideways-lr;   /* Webkit browsers don't support `sideways-lr` yet */
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;  /* `vertical-rl` and a rotation will achieve the same effect */
    transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    height: 100%;

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.85;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You'll end up with a div stacked on the side of your parent div, with the text at a 90° angle.

This way you don't have to think about the rotation origin.

Comment: Thank you! This is the cleanest answer IMO.

Comment: Please note that writing-mode vertical-rl is not broadly supported as of Nov 2018: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

If you need to position wrapper div.and rotate child div so that its always centered vertically and horizontally, try something like this!

```
.togglewrap{
position:relative;
float:left;left:20%;top:0;
width:30px; 
height:120px;
background-color: #ffde21;
}
.sbartoggle {
    background:#f5f5f5;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%; 
    height:30px;/*equal to parent width*/
    line-height:30px;/*center text*/
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background-size:10px 10px;
    }
```